# logging with subprocess in Python

Tags: java, python, subprocess

I am launching a Java command through subprocess in Python.

```
JAVA_CMD = ['java', '-Xmx10200m', '-cp', '/path/to/class', '-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/path/to/logfile']
filename,k,mail = '/path/to/file2',"20", 'help@so.com'
subprocess.Popen(JAVA_CMD + [filename,K,mail], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
## rest of the code
```

Above command runs for 24-48 hours.

Does anyone know if the logging in java command will work with above command? Currently I am able to launch the java command without having to wait for the response but, logging is not working. It is not creating any log files.

Also, is there an automatic timeout related to above process? One of the commands is dying again and again. It might be a problem in the code but I was wondering if subprocess has a timeout related to it which is killing the process.

Ideally what I want is the ability to launch a java command from within Python as if the command was launched by the user and the process should keep on running indefinitely, till it is completed. Python should be able to work on further without having to worry about the java command launched.